# Java read txt and manipulate

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a program that i am working on that I want to do the following to a txt file

1. Manipulate the following string of text abc#.fruit.date
2. Change # to a number between 1 and 9
3. Change fruit to a fruit type like apple
4. Change date to current date in YYYYMMDD format
5. Store the string value into a variable to use in other parts of the program

What I have now is just the bones of it and none of the meat as I am struggling to develop algorithm 
Code is as follows

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.FileReader; 

import Java.util.Scanner;
public class Text { 
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt")))); {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("unable to open file");
        }
    }
}
```

Text.txt looks like

```
abc#.fruit.date
```

Comment: It does look like there are syntax errors, please go through your code and fix syntax errors.

Comment: I might just split the string on the #. chars, instead of using a scanner.

Comment: Your question not clear, please provide more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the proper replacements and print out the result to System.out. All converted lines of the text file will be in the `List<String> output`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fruits[] = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}; //put whatever fruit values you want in here
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt")))) {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            line = line.replaceAll("#", String.valueOf(randomNumber(1, 9)));
            line = line.replaceAll("fruit", fruits[randomNumber(0, fruits.length-1)]);
            line = line.replaceAll("date", new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD").format(new Date()));
            output.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file.");
    }

    for (String line : output) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

private static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Input:

```
abc#.fruit.date
```

Example output:

```
abc7.Apple.201508223
```

Comment: What is wrong with DD format does not give correct number for the day

Comment: Yup, I thought you might not want that format, but that's what you specified. I'm guessing you switched it to lowercase dd.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that did not know that would happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need `String` class method `replace`

and `Calendar.getInstace`. Then after that `SimpleDateFormat`